# How to pass powershell variable from one session to another or from one stage to another in terms of Jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

Every time I close the powershell session or window all the variable created in there is destroyed. Is there any command or way to create a variable which does not gets destoryed evenafter the session is closed. 
I know using script works but my situation is that my jenkins stage opens one window and creates a variable and the stage is closed which closes the session and in the next stage the new session is opened but all the initial variables are lost. I tried using jenkins environment variable but even though it is updated inside the powershell script but in next session it again gets same variable back.

Comment: Have you tried Export-Clixml and Import-Clixml to persist your variables to a file and then re-read them when your other session starts.

Comment: I will try this but I am trying not to use any files as much as possible since the output of my variables are the piped output from some cmdlets.

Comment: Even if I set the variable as an environment variable in one session but whenever another session is opened it shows it as a null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example Session 1 our variable is set to a value of 1.

```
$a = 1
$a | export-clixml -path c:\temp\a.xml
```

now close the session then run this code after you relaunch Powershell or a newly started session.

```
if(test-path c:\temp\a.xml)
{
    $a = import-clixml -Path c:\temp\a.xml
}

$a
1
```