# Jenkinsfile Powershell - variable from one session to another?

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a cleaner way (**NOT** using a file or export-clixml) to pass powershell variable from one session to another or from one stage to another in terms of Jenkinsfile.

I'm trying to avoid using the following from link below:
[How to pass powershell variable from one session to another or from one stage to another in terms of Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637777/how-to-pass-powershell-variable-from-one-session-to-another-or-from-one-stage-to)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of PowerShell you can take a variable from one `PSSession`, and set it in another `PSSession` with:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $variable {
  Set-Variable VariableName $args[0]
}
```

But if the execution engine is NOT PowerShell (such as in this case, you are using the Jenkinsfile to run two instances of `powershell.exe` at different stages), you only have two options:

- Set the output from a shell command to a variable in the Jenkinsfile, and reference it later when building your next PowerShell command
- Serialize the PowerShell object to disk  with `Export-CliXml` and read it in from a different PowerShell session using `Import-CliXml`, [as outlined in the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638145/584676)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try both.